# How do I find the IP address of routers and switches on my network?

Tags: networking, router

I'm attempting to reach the management consoles of three separate devices on my network (a Juniper SRX100, a Unifi Dream Machine Pro, and a Netgear GS108E).  The Juniper has taken 192.168.1.1, and I presume has assigned the Unifi something else (it would normally be on 192.168.1.1).  Similarly, the netgear is not at 192.168.0.239 (its default address.)

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on the machine I am using to attempt to access the management consoles.

Comment: Look at the management device of whichvev3er is responsible for DHCP, or in the case of a static IP address, look at the device where you have set it for each device.

Comment: If more than one device is DHCP server then there is a big mix-up. I suggest connecting the devices one-by-one to your computer via ethernet and checking their settings. You might need to disconnect from all other devices and give your computer a static IP in the default range of the device.

Comment: Finding IP addresses of devices like switches may be hard if they do not have an IP address in the subnet you are in (ie a switch - even a managed one can be invisible to the network).    I might try a subnet scan, then look at the first 3 letters of the MAC addresses for found devices to help guess what they are - there are tools that can largely automate this.  I believe "sudo nmap -sn 192.168.x.0/Y" where x.x is your subnet and Y is your netmask will scan for all devices in that subnet and look up who the manufacturer is.  Of-course this assumes all the routers are in the same subnet.

Comment: if I've done nothing explicit would I expect x and y to be 0 and 24 ?

Comment: (Or, how can I find the values of x and y?)

Comment: I've posted a more specific question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1736500/how-can-i-connect-to-the-netgear-gs108e-management-console

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for the Juniper network *gateway* (AKA *switch* or *consumer router*).

You can get *gateway* along with *mask* information from the `Kernel IP routing table` with either of:

```
netstat -rn
route -n
```

Typically a gateway ends with `1` and is either of:

- `192.168.1.1`
- `192.168.0.1`

This seems to be your Juniper device, operating as your switch. That is probably the address to access your Juniper's "management console".

---

### IP addresses for other devices might not matter

It all depends on your purpose.

*As for the Netgear device, you didn't specify what you are using it for. Since the Juniper has a standard gateway address, it seems you want to use the Netgear to expand your LAN (for either WiFi distance or more ethernet plugs), which means you probably want to turn off DHCP on the Netgear so the Juniper is your only DHCP server. You mentioned three devices, but only named those two. So, this is only a guess.*

If you want to find IP addresses of other "peer" machines connected to your network, you really need a [scanning tool (software)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669585/) to ping all IP addresses. Until then, you may not know your Netgear's address. *But, if your purpose is to expand the network as just described, then you don't need to find the Netgear device's address...*

If you disable the DHCP server on your Netgear device, then the Juniper's DHCP server should handle the Netgear's network IP address, and you won't need to configure the Netgear beyond plugging it in. That is probably why you want to access your Netgear "management console"—to disable it's DHCP server.

If you want to get to the "management console" of your Netgear device:

1. Unplug your Netgear device from the Juniper network.
2. Plug/connect your Ubuntu machine into the Netgear device the same as you would for the consumer router for a home or office.
3. Run `netstat -rn` or `route -n` on your Ubuntu machine and probably find Netgear at `192.168.1.1` or `192.168.0.1`, listed under `Gateway` on the output.

From that gateway IP address, you should be able to access the Netgear "management console", then prepare it how you want, then plug it back into the Juniper and try to proceed from there.