# How can I connect to the Netgear GS108E management console?

Tags: networking, router

First, I factory reset then power reset the GS108E.

Then I plugged only my laptop into it.  The GS108E was unable to give my laptop an IP address (I presume because it is unmanaged or doesn't have DHCP?).

I then plugged the GS108E into my main router, a Juniper SRX100.

My laptop is now able to gain an IP address (and see the outside network.)

However, I cannot find the GS108E's management console.

The default IP is 192.168.0.239 - but trying to access that gives no response.

I used the Netgear Switch Discovery Tool, and it said it found no Netgear devices on the network.

I cannot locate the GS108E anywhere in the SRX100's management console (to try to find a reassinged ip)

Running traceroute [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) on my laptop does not report anything about the GS108E - the first IP given is the SRX100.

#### How can I access the GS108E's management console?

Comment: Is the default IP address within your current LAN subnet? (Also, don't expect a switch to show up on traceroute.)

Comment: How would I find out what the current LAN subnet is - would that be in the SRX100's config?

Comment: Generally you can just look at your computer's current IP settings, i.e. `ipconfig` or `ip -4 addr`. (The settings may be distributed from the router via DHCP but in the end it's the computer from which you're trying to reach the device that matters most.)

Comment: "inet 192.168.1.40/24 brd 192.168.1.255"... so maybe that implies that 192.168.0.239 would not be in the subnet

Comment: I have now done sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24 and this has shown me several devices but not the switch, so I presume it is *not* on the subnet - how could I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First, I factory reset then power reset the GS108E.
>
> Then I plugged only my laptop into it. The GS108E was unable to give my laptop an IP address (I presume because it is unmanaged or doesn't have DHCP?).

Switches don't give out IP addresses to devices. Yes, it's because the switch doesn't have DHCP, but it is *not part of the job* of a switch to have DHCP in the first place – typically this is the router's task, and even managed switches typically wouldn't have DHCP service.

(Enterprise "L3 switches" may be an exception, but that's because they're basically routers anyway.)

Your GS108E **is** a "managed" switch, literally because it has a management console. ('Managed' here just means it's possible to manage it in some way, whether it's a web UI or a serial console.)

> I then plugged the GS108E into my main router, a Juniper SRX100.
>
> My laptop is now able to gain an IP address (and see the outside network.)
>
> The default IP is 192.168.0.239 - but trying to access that gives no response.

Currently, your computer and presumably also your router think that 192.168.1.0/24 is the local subnet. Meaning, they don't know that 192.168.0.239 is local physically – the subnet mask says it's not, so your packets go to router and from there to the WAN instead.

(Although the packets may pass *through* the switch, it will not pay attention to them unless they're sent to the switch's own MAC address, which is generally how IP over Ethernet always works.)

And similarly, the switch's default configuration also won't consider *your* IP address as local, so even if you manually added a "direct" route for .0.0/24 and succeeded in sending packets to the switch's address, it couldn't reply to you anyway (either it would try to use a gateway that doesn't exist, or it wouldn't have any gateway configured yet).

To work around this, temporarily change your computer's IP configuration to a static address within the switch's subnet – in your case, choose an address within 192.168.0.0/24. (All devices I've seen use /24 for their factory default configuration, so it's a good start.) You don't need to specify a gateway or DNS servers when doing this.

Since you're apparently running Linux, you can `ip addr add 192.168.0.11/24` the new address without even removing the normal one – that way you'll be in two subnets simultaneously.

(Changing the router's configuration to use 192.168.0.x/24 is also an option, but in this case completely unnecessary – it's easier to temporarily reconfigure just the computer. As soon as the computer thinks an address is within the local subnet, it won't rely on the router to reach it anyway – that's what the "local subnet" defines.)

> Running traceroute [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) on my laptop does not report anything about the GS108E - the first IP given is the SRX100.

Normally switches will not show up on traceroute, as they're completely invisible to IP layer – they won't even look at the IP headers, much less decrement IP TTLs, so they are not considered a routing hop. (That's why they're switches and not routers.)

Comment: @user1686 - Your `ip addr add 192.168.0.11/24` syntax isn't correct.