# cannot access modem router configuration page when gateway shows a IPV6 address

Tags: router, ipv6, gateway

I want to get to the configuration page tu turn on wifi. but 192.168.0.1 doesn't work. and default gateway shows a IPV6 address.

```
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::201:5cff:fe9f:6c45%10
                                    24.70.80.1
```

tried in both IE and Chrome browsers with following IP addresses

```
192.168.0.1
http://192.168.0.1
fe80::201:5cff:fe9f:6c45%10
http://fe80::201:5cff:fe9f:6c45%10
http://[fe80::201:5cff:fe9f:6c45%10]
24.70.80.1
http://24.70.80.1
```

none of the above address can get to the configuration page.

tried factory reset the modem, ipconfig /release /renew, restart the computer, restart the modem,

still cannot access the modem config page.

```
ping 192.168.0.1

Pinging 192.168.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
```

has response.

how can to get access to the modem configuration page?

Comment: What does the manufacturer's documentation say?  There is ALWAYS a basic setup page in the documentation.  Is the modem yours? or does it belong to the ISP?

Comment: Hitron 4582. the manual says 192.168.0.1  I tried, didn't work. ping 192.168.0.1 has a response. the default gateway is an IPV6 address. tried the factory reset the modem and clear the computer ipconfig. remove and re-installed the network card drive. restarted still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with DOCSIS modems, but this sounds like a situation similar to this yesterday's post:

- [How can I connect to the Netgear GS108E management console?](https://superuser.com/questions/1736500/how-can-i-connect-to-the-netgear-gs108e-management-console/)

i.e. your modem is currently in "bridge" mode, and you're getting your IP configuration directly from the ISP rather than from the modem. (You didn't post the full "ipconfig" output, but I'm going to guess your IPv4 address is 24.70.80.x or similar, too.)

So try configuring your computer's IP address to temporarily be in the modem's local subnet (i.e. 192.168.0.x/24).

The second possibility – if the modem was provided to you by the ISP – is that its configuration pages were deliberately set to be inaccessible by the user. That is, the ISP may *want* the modem to be only used in modem/bridge mode, with you connecting a dedicated router for Wi-Fi.

The presence of an IPv6 gateway has nothing to do with the problem. (For one, it's not "the" default gateway – you have two of them, one for IPv4 and one for IPv6.)

Comment: the second possibility is likely. the modem is retired from a company. it somehow gives me three times more speed than my plan with my ISP. only the computer connected to the modem via network cable has internet.  nothing else connected to the modem has internet. even when connect just dedicated router alone.

Comment: It's probably locked onto the computer's MAC address – I've heard that cable/DOCSIS ISPs do that often. Try configuring the dedicated router's WAN interface to clone your computer's MAC address.